# Creating Jar file with an Inherited Class

Tags: java, inheritance, jar

My Program.java is a class declared like so:

```
public class Program extends JFrame {
...
```

The program compiles and runs just fine, but when I'm creating a jar file I am recieing this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Program/jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Program.jar
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
```

Here is how I am creating the jar file (Linux):

```
javac Program.java
echo Main-Class: Program >manifest.txt
jar cvfm Program.jar manifest.txt Program.class
```

Is this because I'm not including JFrame.class in with my jar creation? If so, is the source for JFrame available so I can include it?

Thank you and have a good one!

Comment: to run jar files you use java -jar <jar file.jar>

Comment: Could you provide the line where the exact problem comes? and is there a class named jar in your program?

Comment: The Swing classes are part of the JDK; you don't need to compile it yourself.

Comment: Regarding your second question, all standard java source code is available somewhere on oracle.com

Comment: Is your Program class in a package ?
If yes, you should use Main-Class: package.Program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look for the following things:

- Your jar file contains a Manifest file on META-INF
- That manifest file includes the main class.
- Your .class files are on the appropriate folders.
- Your main class has a `public static void main(String[] args)` method.

Then you should be able to run the program by calling

```
java -jar yourjar.jar
```

Cheers.

Comment: Hi,

Items 2 through 4 are all satisfied, I'm not sure about the first item regarding META-INF - what has to be done with that?